# nsswitch.conf - name resolution options what is db?

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns, configuration

**TLDR:**
In `nsswitch.conf` there is a `db` service. What type of db is that? What path does nsswitch look for it? How can it be used to store `hosts`?

**WHY:**
I want setup a fallback IP if DNS resolution fails and I have found this answer on super-user:
[set-fallback-ip-address-for-hostname](https://superuser.com/questions/526463/set-fallback-ip-address-for-hostname-in-windows-and-ubuntu)

This is good but going to DNS server all-the-time is not the best as mentioned in another answer here: [using-a-static-fallback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840175/using-a-static-fallback-etc-hosts-if-all-other-dns-options-failed)
At the above link it is also concluded that such fallback is not possible.

I have also checked the man page for `nsswitch.conf` where the `FILES` section mentions resolver services are defined by libs:

```
  A  service  named  SERVICE   is   implemented   by   a   shared   object   library   named
  libnss_SERVICE.so.X that resides in /lib.
```

So the static fallback should be possible it just need to be provided by a different service.
The man page also mentions the `db` service: `/lib/libnss_db.so.X      implements "db" source.`
However I didn't really find any further info about this `db` service.

Seems Ubuntu uses this `db` option in `nsswitch.conf` by default:

```
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
```

The strange thing is that there is no `/lib/libnss_db.so.X` on my system as mentioned at the man page:

```
~$ ll /lib*/ | grep libnss
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38K april  7 03:24 libnss_compat-2.31.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 april  7 03:24 libnss_compat.so.2 -> libnss_compat-2.31.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K april  7 03:24 libnss_dns-2.31.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 april  7 03:24 libnss_dns.so.2 -> libnss_dns-2.31.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54K april  7 03:24 libnss_files-2.31.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   20 april  7 03:24 libnss_files.so.2 -> libnss_files-2.31.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26K april  7 03:24 libnss_hesiod-2.31.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 april  7 03:24 libnss_hesiod.so.2 -> libnss_hesiod-2.31.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  54K april  7 03:24 libnss_nis-2.31.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62K april  7 03:24 libnss_nisplus-2.31.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   22 april  7 03:24 libnss_nisplus.so.2 -> libnss_nisplus-2.31.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   18 april  7 03:24 libnss_nis.so.2 -> libnss_nis-2.31.so
```

Comment: There are a bunch of tutorials on the web about `nsswitch.conf` most of them focuses on DNS, but they just conveniently skip this `db` service and just focus on the most common `files`, `dns` and `mdns4`.

Answer (score 1):

Each database (in terms of NSS) demands to use its own lookup functions. Say, for services database it's `getservbyname_r()`, for protocols database it's `getprotobyname_r()`.
The hosts database wants to use `gethostbyaddr_r()` and `gethostbyname_r()`.
So when you declare `db` in the `hosts` line in your `nsswitch.conf`, the nss code loads `libnss_db.so` and tries to find `_nss_db_gethostbyname_r()` in it.
Helas there's no one. Because the `db` service doesn't support hosts database.

I had the same need and spent another day to experiment and dig into glibc sources. And I conclude the only way is to implement your own nss plugin with needed functions to use other files then `/ets/hosts` for the hosts database.

Use the command like `nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2` to  display lookup functions in the service library to find out which implements what.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/600503):

> db causes libnss_db to be used. That reads data from Berkeley DB files usually stored in /var/db (/var/lib/misc on Debian); this is typically faster than reading from plain text files, for large NSS databases.
>
> You should be able to modify the databases with a Berkeley DB client, but they’re typically built wholesale from the relevant source data. In the configuration above, the data sources are text files in /etc, and these remain the reference; the DB file is a variant used for speed, built wholesale using makedb, and not intended as the primary storage. The text files here are /etc/protocols for protocols, /etc/services for services, /etc/ethers for Ethernet addresses, /etc/rpc for RPC program numbers.
>
> It’s more common to see db used for the passwd and group databases, as a local cache for large, remotely-hosted user databases (typically using LDAP).

You can get your hands on `makedb` command by installing `libnss-db` package. If we take a look into what has been installed, you'll find `libnss_db.so`.

```
dpkg -L libnss-db | grep so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db-2.2.3.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2
```

This package also installs a `Makefile` at `/var/lib/misc/Makefile`.
`cd` into `/var/lib/misc/` and run `sudo make`, it will generates a set of `db` files for you:

```
$ ls /var/lib/misc/
group.db  Makefile  passwd.db  protocols.db  rpc.db  services.db  shadow.db
```

You can also generate one manually:

```
$ makedb /etc/passwd ~/passwd.db
$ file ~/passwd.db
~/passwd.db: Berkeley DB (Btree, version 9, native byte-order)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I don't understand how I didn't find it.
The install worked and I could create the `hosts.db`, but `nsswitch.conf` doesn't find/use it. Tried `/var/lib/misc/`, `/etc/` and `/var/db/` none of them worked.